# Self assignment for NSString category

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, variable-assignment, categories, init

I want to self assign an adjusted nsstring via category.
The example is a trim function:

I do not want that way:

```
NSString *theTempString = [theExampleString xTrim];
// ... go on doing stuff with theTempString
```

I want it this way:

```
[theExampleString xTrim];
// ... go on doing stuff with theExmapleString
```

The category looks like this:

```
- (void)xTrim
{
    self = [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

}
```

The error that an assignment outside init is not possible - I understand that.
But now I'm interested in it, of course I can write an custom init methode, but is there no way around it like the one above???

Greetings and thanks,

matthias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create a new NSString, the method already does that for you:

```
- (NSString *)xTrim
{
    return [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
}
```

NSString is immutable so you need to assign it:

```
yourString = [yourString xTrim];
```

Comment: damn, thanks a lot for giving me the kick in the a...of course NSString is not a mutable ... arrrrgh... –

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that in a category on `NSString`, because `NSString` manages *immutable strings*, which means that the string can not be changed after it has been created.

You could implement it as category on `NSMutableString`:

```
- (void)xTrim
{
    NSString *trimmed = [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    [self setString:trimmed]; // replaces the characters of "self" with those of "trimmed".
}
```

And if your question is: Can I write a method  `xTrim` such that

```
[theExampleString xTrim]
```

**replaces** the receiver `theExampleString` with a new instance: No, that is not possible.

Comment: damn, thanks a lot for giving me the kick in the a...of course NSString is not a mutable ... arrrrgh...